# How to exclude numbers that start with currency symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to ignore a number that represents a price anywhere in text.

It should match

```
3.5 mm
-2
#1
```

It should ignore

```
$3.50
```

So far I have a Regex for Javascript

```
([^\$¢£]([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?))([^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

but this will still match the 3.50 just exluding the dollar sign.
What is missing to ignore the the whole number?

EDIT:
For testing https://regex101.com/r/9SLNo2/1

Comment: What about USD3.50?

Comment: @RobG no. That would be an edge case so I can ignore it

Comment: you want to escape these symbols $¢£ from the beginning of numbers?

Comment: Where "edge case" means "looks too difficult to I'll ignore it…" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor the match to the start of the string by adding a `^` to the front. I do not really understand what you are trying to accomplish by the most of your regular expression though.

If you just want anything that doesn't start with a currency symbol, try `^[^\$¢£].*$`.
Anything that doesn't contain *any* currency symbol, try `^[^\$¢£]*$`.
Anything that contains a number (optionally decimal, always contain the whole part like you seem to intend), surrounded optionally by "non-currency symbols", try `^[^\$¢£]*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[^\$¢£]*$`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, lookbehinds are not supported in `JS`but you could use a "trick":
*match* anything you **don't want** but *capture* anything you **do want**:

```
junk_a|junk_b|junk_c|(interesting_stuff)
```

So here with your specific example:

```
[$¢£]\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)*)
# ^^^^^ junk part ^^^^^
```

---

Afterwards, use a little comparison that checks if the group 1 (the `interesting_stuff`) is set:

```js
let data = 'lorem ipsum 3.5 mm -2 #1 lorem ipsum $3.50 lorem ipsum';
let regex = /[\$¢£]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*|(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)*)/g;
let interesting = [];

while ((match = regex.exec(data)) !== null) {
    if (typeof(match[1]) != "undefined") {
        interesting.push(match[1]);
    }
}

console.log(interesting);
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9SLNo2/2) (needs to be tweaked for the units).

Answer (score 0):

You could just ignore values that begin with a dollar sign...

```js
var values = ['3.5 mm', '-2', '#1', '$3.50'];

var regex = new RegExp('^\\$');
var res = values.filter(function(val) {
  if (val.match(regex)) {
    console.log(val, 'skip');
  } else {
  return val;
  }
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check() { // if you want to match only numbers at the bigining as well as #
  var a = document.getElementById("test").value;
  var remove = /^-?\d*\.?\d+|#/;
  var b = a.match(remove);
  if (!b)
    console.log("ignore");
  else
    console.log("true");
}

function check2() { // if you want to ignore first charcter if match these $,¢ and £ and allow others
  var a = document.getElementById("test").value;
  var remove = ['$', '¢', '£'];
  var b = a.charAt(0);
  if (remove.indexOf(b) != -1)
    console.log("ignore");
  else
    console.log("true");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="check();check2()" id="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, maybe you could match the numbers that represent a price and replace the match with an empty string:

[`[£$¢]\d+(?:\.\d+)? *`](https://regex101.com/r/ua9NXk/1)

```js
var pattern = /[£$¢]\d+(?:\.\d+)? */g;
var text = `3.5 mm
This is 3.5 mm.
-2
This is -2 and test
This is #1 and test
#1
$3.50
$3.50
This is $3.50.
This is $3.50 a test
This is a £100000 test and $5000.00 test.
This is a ¢100000 test`;

console.log(text.replace(pattern, ""));
```